# How can I get html code from Webpage with login?

Tags: authentication, uwp, webrequest

I want to get the HTML Code from a [Webpage](https://kundenkonto.lidl-connect.de/login.html) (German Prepaid Provider).

I tried it with Webrequest but this does not work.

```
async private void connectToLidlConnect()
        {
        string user = UserName;
        string pass = Password;

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "login=" + user + "&mdp=" + pass;
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://kundenkonto.lidl-connect.de/login.html");
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers["ContentLength"] = data.Length.ToString();

        using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    //
                    var a = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I navigate to the next page with Cookies?

I Tried this too:

```
                async public Task LogIn()
    {
        CookieContainer container;

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LoginPageAdress);

        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(loginData.ToString());
        request.Headers["ContentLength"] = buffer.Length.ToString();
        var requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        container = request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        var request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://kundenkonto.lidl-connect.de/mein-lidl-connect/mein-tarif/uebersicht.html"));
        request1.CookieContainer = container;

        var webResponse = await request1.GetResponseAsync();

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)webResponse;

        // Get the stream associated with the response.
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        var html = readStream.ReadToEnd();

        CookieContainer = container;

        requestStream.Dispose();
        response.Dispose();
        readStream.Dispose();
        webResponse.Dispose();


    }
```

But with this I only get the html from the Login page... It seems that i am using the cookiecontainer wrong.

So I got from Fiddler this Information (I Changed my LoginData Username=xxxxxxxxxxx; Password XXXXXXXXXXXX):

POST ttps://kundenkonto.lidl-connect.de/login.html HTTP/1.1

Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*

Referer: ttps://kundenkonto.lidl-connect.de/login.html

Accept-Language: de-DE

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Host: kundenkonto.lidl-connect.de

Content-Length: 109

Connection: Keep-Alive

Cache-Control: no-cache

Cookie: resolution=1440; PHPSESSID=td1ee0rkkv7qr72ku6ilk1gq55

lastpage=1&REQUEST_TOKEN=51ae54e320c2cc7aa64302be163a0c5a&msisdn_msisdn=xxxxxxxxxxx&password=XXXXXXXXXXXX

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text / html, application / xhtml + xml, image / jxr");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language"," de-DE");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User - Agent", "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 52.0.2743.116 Safari / 537.36 Edge / 15.15063");
```

maybe someone can help me:)

Thank You :)

Comment: I would suggest you capturing network track using Fiddler and comparing with what you have done in a web browser. Using this tool, you can check the cookie you got and request the page with this cookie

Comment: I tried it with fiddler but i don't really know how to use it to get informations. May be somewere is an example for a login an get data from a user page.

Comment: Search for UWP/WINRT Fiddler. For example, this doc is for WIn8 app, but the configuration is the same: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureFiddlerForWin8

Comment: I edited my post with some Fiddler Informations. I tried to connect to thos page but it did not work...